# What connection should I use for a dynamic file

Tags: uml

I have to create a class diagram for a tree structure of a filesystem.
I have directory/folder named **myfolder**. In that folder I have two files: **file1**  and **file2**. **file1** will be there forever so I have a composition between **file1** and **myfolder**. On the other hand **file2** will appear and disappear because it is a product of compiled **file1**. When I tell the build file to clean the target **file2** disappears.

What connection should I use between **myfolder** and **file2**?
What connection should I use between **file1** and **file2**?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to create a class diagram for a filesystem, or describe this particular behavior? Because the filesystem itself doesn't care about the reasons why a particular file is created. (From filesystem's perspective, there is no difference between file1 and file2)

Comment: To clarify further: Class diagram is a **structural** diagram, but "When I make clean, file2 disappears" is a description of a behavior --- that's what **behavior** diagrams are for.

Comment: A funny question. Inexperienced analytic would mix the dependency of classes File and Folder and physical belonging of files to folders. Too much dependencies... +1 for so hard questions a start.

Answer (score 2):

I am using a deployment diagram for that. To symbolize a folder I use a package stereotyped as `<<folder>>` and for file simple artifacts like this:

[image]

Of course this will only show a static configuration. Dynamic behavior will be caused by some object interaction for which you can use sequence diagrams. Or use informal notes/constraints.

Comment: You have mixed all possible things here. The question was not about packages. And packages do not belong to Deployment diagram. The last is about placement of components into different pieces of HW: servers, clients and so on. So, you answer different question and badly.

Comment: Well, I know that it's a mesh-up but the reader instantly knows what is meant. So I have no pain using it.

Comment: @Gangnus and not to forget: UML allows to create your own profile. So I call this a file-deployment diagram and by using my own stereotype I'm absolutely conforming to the specs.

Comment: And you really think that a beginner needs so non-standard use of diagrams? And he will be able to persuade his colleagues to use it this way? I love non-standard use of diagrams. For example, class diagrams for UI modelling. But sorry, it is not for starters.

Comment: @Gangnus It's not a question of beginner/advanced but of communication. I have not met anyone being unclear about what the diagram tells. If you get the message over it's fine. No matter what the specs tell you.

Answer (score 1):

The Class diagram does not work with the objects themselves, but with the classes. (You CAN use objects in it, but their use is not the theme of this diagram normally)

[image]

Of course, you can add many fields to the File, such as name, Date and so on, but the bulk is here.

If you want to show the concrete structure of dependency of objects, use Object diagram instead:

[image]

These connections with crosses in circles mean containment.

BTW, you can show the package on the class diagram, too, and not include classes rectangles into the package rectangle, but connect them with containment relationship, too, if you wish. But notice, packages tell us not about the product that the client get, but about organization of your classes in your source code. Usually package diagram tells about that, but you can show it on the class diagram, too.

Composition means that item belongs only to the collection in a natural way and can't belong to any other. But it is for classes, not objects.

The fact of appearing and disappearing of something can not be shown in the **structure diagrams**, such as Deployment, Component, Package, Class and Object. You should use **interactions diagrams** for that - State, Sequence, Activity, Timing.

But, hooray! There is always such thing as a comment. You can put comments on both containment connections and simply write in them, that one is forever, and the other one appears and disappears.

As for relationship between file1 and file2 use Dependency arrow with text explanation on it.

Comment: "Class diagram does not work with the objects" is incorrect. See Note on p. 683 UML 2.5: "...it does not preclude mixing different kinds of diagram types, as one might do when one combines structural and behavioral elements..."

Comment: @ThomasKilian Thank you. Yes, of course, it is possible to put elements from any diagram into any other diagram. But the questioner is a beginner. He needs to learn first how to divide the info between the diagrams, and only later, when he will be able to use them, he can allow himself to mix them.